# Verb for the act of making a "Tch" sound

Tags: single-word-requests

This has been bothering me (a native English speaker) for a long time. It seems almost impossible outside of dialogue to describe the act of unconsciously spitting out a "Tch!" in response to something outrageous, comedic, etc. For example:

> Bob tch'ed at Mary's absurd suggestion.
>
> John merely tch'ed at the punchline and returned to his work.
>
> Sally tch'ed and rolled her eyes. "He can't be serious!"

In want of the proper verb or phrase for this action, I often have to resort to just *choosing* another action for my written character to perform so that I can describe it better. But it's not very real to life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use "chuffed".

**chuff** n. 1. A sound of or like the exhaust of a steam engine.  - v.i. 2. to emit or proceed with chuffs.  *The train chuffed along.*

Webster's Encyclopedic Unabridged Dictionary of the English Language 1996 edition.

Comment: Ah, this is actually quite a good suggestion for describing the noise itself. Unfortunately, I can't find any dictionaries or prior usages attesting to its usage in this context.

Comment: @Feryll https://books.google.com/books?id=vgc9BgAAQBAJ&pg=PT97&lpg=PT97&dq=%22chuffed+in+disapproval%22&source=bl&ots=RcdZaq3umP&sig=6zG88HAFgeqTaPbhAXlWpxs0Uog&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwif7ffU6PTVAhVh5YMKHfJCCAsQ6AEIKzAA#v=onepage&q=%22chuffed%20in%20disapproval%22&f=false

Comment: @Feryll https://books.google.com/books?id=rD5UCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT189&lpg=PT189&dq=%22chuffed+with+surprise%22&source=bl&ots=aSiNxxlYLI&sig=j4-yWci7lmWEi-YM45vcyrG84Ac&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjQ5JDI6fTVAhXKzIMKHdyjAi8Q6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22chuffed%20with%20surprise%22&f=false

Comment: Nice. I shall support this usage until the day I die!

Answer (score 3):

I had a professor who often used *tut* or *tut-tut* to express disapproval.

From [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tut):

> **tut** (interjection, verb)
>
> used to express disapproval or disbelief
>
> *intransitive verb* tutted, tutting.

E.g., Bob tutted at Mary's absurd suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

"Tsked" is an acceptable way to spell the sound you're thinking of.

> interjection
>
> 1. (used, often in quick repetition, as an exclamation of contempt, disdain, impatience, etc.)
> 2. for shame!

Source: [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/tsked)

Comment: Saying "tsk, tsk, tsk" is something entirely different, though. It's not only a different sound that can't be used in the same circumstances (e.g. as a response to a joke), but "tsk" usually implies a conscious disapproval, rather than a (culturally relative) gut reaction.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree that "tsk" implies "conscious disapproval." // How would you transcribe "tch," if not identically to "tsk"?

Comment: They're both dental clicks, but they're different sounds, to be sure. I've only ever seen "tsk" as [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-imfjwhDM0A) as synonymous to (as dictionary.com confirms) "for shame!" However, the "tch" as at 0:10 [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kibwDQpqtA4) sounds different, is never repeated, and can be used where "tsk (tsk tsk)" cannot be.

Comment: Neither of those sounds is a dental click. But I will think on it.